# What are the Chinese characters for the American English word "Dishonored"?

Tags: translation, mandarin, cantonese, simplified-characters, traditional-characters

Related to the video game Dishonored. I'm not looking for the characters for 'Ashamed' or 'Insulted', words that would not work to properly describe in English the game title :D. Any other choices? I need something like 'I lost my honor by being betrayed' or 'the betrayal stole my honor'. Thanks!

Comment: 耻辱 or 羞辱, 被人出卖是我的耻辱, 对我是一种羞辱. It's a noun, In modern Chinese, we usually describe it with a noun. 蒙羞 is the more accurate one to dishonored, but the word is only used in classical Chinese.  btw, the video game is called 耻辱 or 羞辱 by Chinese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game is called

- [耻辱](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%86%A4%E7%BD%AA%E6%AE%BA%E6%A9%9F) on the mainland.
- 羞辱 also on the mainland
- 冤罪杀机 in HK & TW

Some of the details might not be 100% accurate as it looks like Wikipedia is giving contradictory information.

Dishonored 2:

- 耻辱2 (Mainland)
- 羞辱2 (Mainland)
- 冤罪杀机 (HK & TW)

Comment: Thank you for the Wikipedia link!

Answer (score 1):

"汉奸", "狗汉奸" or "叛徒"
Pronounced as Han Jian, Gou Han Jian, or Pantu.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say 背叛之辱 is pretty good as it means feeling humiliated after being betrayed

Answer (score 0):

Can you transliterate  "Dishonored"  and  use "狄仕安纳特" /Dí shì ān nà tè/ ? The original meanings of the characters are irrelevant

As for translation, I think 雪恥者 (the one who seeks to restore his honor) is quite simple and direct . The one who lost his honor by being betrayed would naturally make restore his honor his mission in life

*Chinese editors have a habit of renaming foreign titles instead of translate them, you can give it a new name base on the plot.*